# (log4jdbc + slf4j + logback) how to auto line sort sql log?

Tags: logback, slf4j, log4jdbc

I installed Log4jdbc-log4j2 + slf4j + logback on my dynamic web server project.

During the test, the log and query statements come out as set, but like other people, the query statement does not wrap automatically.

Only one line.

If you set the log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength portion of the log4jdbc.log4j2.properties file to 5,

Line breaks occur as much as the set value, but they are sorted out in a mess.

Previously, when using log4sql it was automatically sorted

sql log is

```
INSERT INTO TB_LOG VALUES ( 'test', 'test', SYSDATE, '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1', '0')
```

i want this (Automatically sorted when using log4sql)

```
INSERT INTO 
  TB_LOG VALUES ( 
    'test'
    , 'test'
    , SYSDATE
    , '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1'
    , '0')
```

How do I auto-align this part?

my setting

log4jdbc.log4j2.properties

```
log4jdbc.spylogdelegator.name=net.sf.log4jdbc.log.slf4j.Slf4jSpyLogDelegator
log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength=0
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration scan="true">
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-35(%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{20} - %msg %n%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="jdbc" level="OFF"/>

  <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="OFF"/>
  <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="DEBUG"/>
  <logger name="jdbc.audit" level="OFF"/>
  <logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="OFF"/>
  <logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="OFF"/>
  <logger name="jdbc.connection" level="OFF"/>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```